# Node.js Project in Nodeclipse Node Perspective Disappeared

Tags: eclipse, node.js, github, egit, nodeclipse

I successfully imported a couple of Node.js projects from GitHub into the **Node Perspective** of the Eclipse.  I was able to run npm install and configurations.

I shut down the Eclipse, powered off the Fedora virtual machine and the host laptop before I left office.

When I came back to office and launched the Eclipse again, the two Node.js projects disappeared from the **Node Perspective**.  I can see them in the **Git Repository Perspective** though.

Why does it happen this way?  What should I do to bring them back to the Node Perspective?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you locate the projects files? Is there .project file inside?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to solve the problem in SO format. Raise an issue https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues